# Analog to Digital converter

Tags: gpio, hardware, sensor, analog-to-digital

Can I connect a ADC0804LCN to a raspberry pi ?

http://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/77309/INTERSIL/ADC0804LCN.html

Comment: I am not expert on electrical engineering, but on page 4 of the referenced manual there is the following Digital Output Specification: http://i.imgur.com/0w2PPKz.png
Now, you just need to check if the Raspberry Pi allows these voltages and amperes.

Answer (score 3):

If you have any choice, you might be better at choosing an A/D converter which has an SPI interface, such as [MCP3008 from Microchip](http://www.microchip.com/wwwproducts/Devices.aspx?dDocName=en010530). It will be far more easy to "talk" with from the raspberry pi as the latter also has an SPI interface available through the GPIO pins.

Adafruit has [a nice tutorial](http://learn.adafruit.com/reading-a-analog-in-and-controlling-audio-volume-with-the-raspberry-pi/overview) on how to use this chip with the Raspberry Pi.

[image: MCP3008 pinout]
[image: Connecting MCP3008 to rpi]